# Does the Qt Quick 2 Scene Graph sync to vsync on EGLFS?

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am studying about Qt Quick 2 in Qt 5.1. It is cool. However, I do not get it about Scene Graph feature. If I just create Flickable, put a bunch of Images to it, and show this in QQuickView on embedded device with EGLFS backend - am I using the Scene Graph or not?

If yes, why do I see tearing - Scene Graph should be VSynced?

If not - what should I do to use it with Flickable? Or does it mean I should implement all from scratch?

My app is basically allowing to browse an endless generated image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QtQuick2 has as its **only** backend the scene graph. So yes, you're using it. Whether that's going to be vsynced, it's another story -- mostly depends whether the scene graph is using a render thread or not, and the quality of the drivers (i.e. if swapping buffers will wait for the vsync). You can try

1. to run your app with the environment variable `QSG_RENDER_TIMING` set to a non-zero value; this will print frame statistics for your application. (See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph-renderer.html) for more info.) If your frame lengths are not an exact multiple of the vsync interval, then you're not having vsync
2. to run your app with the environment variable `QT_QPA_EGLFS_FORCEVSYNC`, which will try to use the `FBIO_WAITFORVSYNC` ioctl to attempt to sync with the vsync.

Comment: Atleast for QT5, its QSG_RENDER_TIMING not QML_RENDER_TIMING

Comment: The environment variables have indeed changed since (checks notes) 2013. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Note the scene graph docs mention a "new" logging support but don't actually give an example. So maybe this helps someone else.

QT_LOGGING_RULES="qt.scenegraph.general=true" ./qmlvideo